# Asyncio Python app running slow on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, web-deployment, python-asyncio

I'm trying to deploy a Python app to Heroku. I use a Python web framework called [Quart](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/), I use quart for its extra asyncio functionality. In my app, I run a loop with websockets, I intend for a message to be frequently sent (updating the client). When I go to my Heroku website, I do receive the websocket messages, but there is a time gap of about 1.5 seconds between the messages (I need them to be sent more frequent).

The apps `Procfile` consists of :

```
web: gunicorn --worker-class quart.worker.GunicornWorker main_loop:app
```

I the app is started with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=os.environ.get('PORT', '5000'))
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be, that you should not mix gunicorn call with app.run. Run app.run with python main_file.py or gunicorn call